# Aligning font when rotated using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

I added a label in the print composer of QGIS (3.6).  I rotated the label, but then the font is no longer aligned to a common line.  I think it is stair-stepping where the letters go, perhaps snapping them to discrete pixels or locations.  I messed around with the Guides and Grid settings, but cannot seem to fix the problem.  I have attached a screen shot, notice the label "survey grid".  It aligns well when I zoom in.
[image: sample map with issue]

Comment: How does it look when you export the map? Is this only a problem in the print composer, or is it also a problem in the exported map image?